# HTML Form field not showing touched status - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, error-handling, runtime-error

I am trying to input some data in a form, but it is not giving me the `touched` status. Therefore, an error will always occur when sending a message back to the user.

I am using `FormBuilder` in my TS file to store the values from the HTML. It gives me this error regardless if I put in data or not.

I am lost.

**The error**

[image]

```
firstName: FormControl {validator: ƒ, asyncValidator: ƒ, _onCollectionChange: 
ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, …}
```

Value:

```
value: {firstName: "", .... }
```

I have tried to check for `pristine` in the `ngIf` condtion, but it doesn't.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formInfo" (ngSubmit)="validateForm()">

  <label>First Name <input type="text" maxlength="35" />
<div *ngIf="submitted && formInfo.controls.firstName.errors" class="error">

  <div *ngIf="(formInfo.controls.firstName.pristine) && (formInfo.controls.firstName.errors.required)">Your first
    name is required.</div>
</div>
</label>
....
 </form>
```

And here's my TypeScript code:

```
 // Class Attributes
 formInfo: FormGroup;
 submitted = false;
 success = false;

 constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) { }

 // Form data as an object
 ngOnInit() {
    this.formInfo = this.builder.group({
     firstName: ['', Validators.required],
     ....
     });
 }

 // Validates the form
 validateForm() {
    this.submitted = true;

    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.formInfo);

   if (this.formInfo.invalid) {
      return;
   }

    this.success = true;
  }
}
```

I just want the form to say, you need to type in a value if the user has not. Otherwise, there will be no error message.

I have added the following code to see if there is even value in my TS file.

```
 <form [formGroup]="formInfo" (ngSubmit)="validateForm()">

  <label>First Name <input type="text" maxlength="35" />
<div *ngIf="submitted && formInfo.controls.firstName.errors" class="error">

  <div *ngIf="(formInfo.controls.firstName.pristine) && (formInfo.controls.firstName.errors.required)">Your first
    name is required.</div>
</div>
</label>
....
 </form>

<!-- I added this -->
<div *ngIf="submitted">
    <strong>First Name</strong>
    <span>{{ formInfo.controls.firstName.value }}</span>
 </div>
```

It seems that the value is never saved into the TS.

Comment: check this for any clues: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-basics-form-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Solve my question you just need to change

```
<form [formGroup]="formInfo" (ngSubmit)="validateForm()">

<label>First Name <input type="text" maxlength="35" />
<div *ngIf="submitted && formInfo.controls.firstName.errors" class="error">

<div *ngIf="(formInfo.controls.firstName.pristine) && 
(formInfo.controls.firstName.errors.required)">Your first
name is required.</div>
</div>
</label>
....
</form>
```

To

```
<form [formGroup]="formInfo" (ngSubmit)="validateForm()">

<label>First Name <input type="text" maxlength="35" formControlName="firstName">
<div *ngIf="submitted && formInfo.controls.firstName.errors" class="error">

<div *ngIf="(formInfo.controls.firstName.pristine) && 
(formInfo.controls.firstName.errors.required)">Your first
name is required.</div>
</div>
</label>
....
</form>
```

Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

`formInfo.controls.firstName.pristine` will be `true` if the user has not yet changed the value in the UI.
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#pristine

You'll want to modify

```
<div *ngIf="(formInfo.controls.firstName.pristine) && (formInfo.controls.firstName.errors.required)">Your first
    name is required.</div>
```

to be

```
<div *ngIf="formInfo.controls.firstName.invalid && formInfo.controls.firstName.errors.required">Your first
    name is required.</div>
```

Comment: It did not work, I get the same error but now it's not showing any error message.

Comment: Please post a plunker or similar.

Comment: @Compilerv2, I just edited my answer, you really should just be checking to see if your validations were valid. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: No, it did not work. Now I get the original error back.